# Java using NetBeans: Issues with Swing buttons

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am new to programming in Java and have no idea how to fix this error that occurs when I press either one of my buttons on the JFrame. I looked around and nothing I find seems to help me to fix these problems. 
This is the JFrame code for my two buttons:

```
    private void btnCheckInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Patient p = null;

        if (this.rbtnChild.isSelected()) {
            p = new Child();
        }
        else if (this.rbtnAdult.isSelected()) {
            p = new Adult();
        }
        else if (this.rbtnElder.isSelected()) {
            p = new Elder();
        }
        p.name = txtName.getText();
        if(txtName.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            lblValid.setText("Enter a Name.");
        }
        h.CheckIn(p); 
        lblResult.setText(p.name + " successfully checked in.");
        txtName.setText("");
    }                                          

    private void btnProcessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Doctor d = h.processNext();
        lblResult.setText(d.name + " looked at your patient " + d.currentPatient.name);
        if(q.isEmpty())
        {
            lblProValid.setText("No Patients in Queue.");
        }
    }
```

When I click the btnProcess, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:268)
at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:683)
at assignmet.Hospital.processNext(Hospital.java:37)
at assignmet.NewJFrame.btnProcessActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:231)
at assignmet.NewJFrame.access$400(NewJFrame.java:14)
at assignmet.NewJFrame$5.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:94)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

When I click on the btnCheckIn it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at assignmet.NewJFrame.btnCheckInActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:220)
at assignmet.NewJFrame.access$300(NewJFrame.java:14)
at assignmet.NewJFrame$4.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:87)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is the hospital class that is mentioned:

```
    package assignmet;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Hospital {

    Queue<Patient> q;
    ArrayList<Doctor> d;

    Hospital() {

        q = new LinkedList<>();
        d = new ArrayList<>();
        d.add(new Doctor("Smith", Qualification.CHILD));
        d.add(new Doctor("Charles", Qualification.ADULT));
        d.add(new Doctor("Jones", Qualification.ELDERLY));

    }

    void CheckIn(Patient p) {
        q.add(p);
    }

    Doctor processNext() {

        Patient p = q.remove();

        for (Doctor doc: d) {

            if (doc.qualification == Qualification.CHILD && 
                    p.getClass() == Child.class)
            {
                doc.currentPatient = p;
                return doc;
            }

            else if (doc.qualification == Qualification.ADULT && 
                    p.getClass() == Adult.class)
            {
                doc.currentPatient = p;
                return doc;
            }

            else if (doc.qualification == Qualification.ELDERLY && 
                    p.getClass() == Elder.class)
            {
                doc.currentPatient = p;
                return doc;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the [JavaDocs for LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove()), remove will throw a NoSuchElementExceptipn when the Queue is empty

Comment: As for your NullPointerException, it's likely that "p" is still null when you attempt to get its name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `NoSuchElementException` is caused by the remove method being called on an empty queue. Make sure the Process button is only enabled when the queue is not empty.

For the `NullPointerException` you can check line 220 of the `NewJFrame` class or share that code (with line numbers) to let us have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` is thrown because you call q.remove() when the queue is empty.

`NullPointerException` is thrown because either p or txtName is null.

Comment: Ok, so either p or txtName is null.

Comment: Thank you for you quick responses. Line 220 is in the btnCheckInActionPerformed method and it is:                                   p.name = txtName.getText(); p is null at the top of the method, but if i erase that to just be Patient p; then it tells me "p may be uninitialized"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Netbeans, it should be easy for use the debugger. You have a Null Pointer Exception at NewJFrame.java:220? Set a breakpoint there and see what's NULL. If it's a case where it legitimately could be NULL, then add some code to perform the action conditionally.

If it's a case where it should not be null. Then you have to dig deeper into your code and understand what the runtime conditions were that got your code into the erroneous state and fix those.